# Maintain count of each change to cell value

Tags: excel, vba, auto-increment

Suppose I have a value in cell A1 and everytime the cell value of `A1` changes, the cell on b1 counts the change.

I have a code it works just with A1(value)cell and b1(count on change) cell. i would like to apply this function on cell `E2:E709` (value) cells and `F2:F709` (count on change) cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Static OldVal As Variant
If Target.Address(False, False) = "A1" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Value <> OldVal Then
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Target.Offset(, 1).Value + 1
    OldVal = Target.Value
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static OldVal(2 To 709) As Variant
    Dim E As Range, F As Range, r As Range, Intersekt As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    Set E = Range("E2:E709")
    Set F = Range("F2:F709")

    Set Intersekt = Intersect(E, Target)
    If Intersekt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Intersekt
            rw = r.Row
            If r.Value <> OldVal(rw) Then
                r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
                OldVal(rw) = r.Value
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

We use an **array** for `OldVal` rather than a **single item**.
We use a *(potentially)* multi-cell `Intersekt`Range` to facilitate changing more than one cell at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, your code works perfectly if I change the value manually but when I apply vlookup function on column "E" then the moves are not counted in column F. Is there any way to count when vlookup is applied on column E.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' If change was outside range we are interested in, then quit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E709")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   ' store reference to cell in F column for simplicity
    Dim c As Range: Set c = Target.Offset(0, 1)
    ' check if cell in F column has any value, if not, then assign it 1
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Value = 1
    ' else increment it by one
    Else
        c.Value = c.Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```